# how do I get a list of the videos of the Itunes media library on IOS?

Tags: ios, listview, video, get, itunes

i want to get a list of all Videos which are in the itunes library, how i get the access to them?
later I want to play them eventually, but not in fullscreen.
i hope you can help me.

Comment: Look at `ALAssetsLibrary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@(MPMediaTypeAnyVideo) forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];
MPMediaQuery *movieQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[movieQuery addFilterPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *allVideos = [movieQuery items];
```